# How to make a vertical line in Plotly draggable

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, draggable

I'm looking to add a layer to a plot with a vertical line that can be dragged left and right in a plot, and have the server calculate how much of the data of the main plot is left and right of that line. Not sure whether this is possible at this moment with plotly.

I know how to calculate whats left and right of a fixed line in a plot, so the question is purely about:

- How to make a plotted vertical line draggable in i.e. Plotly
- How to read the x coordinate of the line when it's dragged

for instance in a simple plot like this one here:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui  <- 
  fluidPage(
   plotlyOutput('Plot1')
       )

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlotly({ plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = mtcars$mpg, y = mtcars$hp, type = 'scatter', 
                          mode = 'markers') %>%
    add_segments(x = 20, xend = 20, y = 0, yend = 350)  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```